# Find a functional and a normed space $X$ such that $\forall x\in X$ with $||x||=1$, $f(x)\neq ||f||$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find a functional $f$ and a normed space $X$ such that $\forall x\in X$ with $||x||=1$, $f(x)\neq ||f||$

My work:

Take $X=l_1$ and we equip it with  supnorm $||.||_\infty$

Take $f\in X'$(dual of X) defined for any $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots ,\xi_n,\cdots)$ as $$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \xi_n $$

Norm of $f_0$ is infinity :

Take a sequence $$(x_n)_k=(\delta_{nk})_k,\quad k=0,1,2,3,\cdots$$

$$||f||=n\to \infty$$

But I cannot show that if $||x||_\infty=1$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty  |\xi_n| $ is finite then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \xi_n $ is always finite for a given fixed $x=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots ,\xi_n,\cdots)$

How can I fix it or how can I try/give another example as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer $\|f\|$ to be $<\infty$.
Also, nobody said that $X$ should be complete.
So take the space $\bigcup_n\Bbb R^n$ of finite sequences with $\|\cdot\|_1$ and define $$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=\sum_n\frac{n}{n+1}x_n.$$
Then $\|\mathbf x\|_1=1$ implies $|f(\mathbf x)|<1$, but we can get arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Does finite sequences mean there are only finite nonzero coordinates in x, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for some Banach spaces as well.  For example, with $X = \ell_1$, take the functional $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (1-1/j) x_j$.  Then $\|f\| = 1$ but for any $x$ with $\|x\|=1$,
$f(x) < 1$.  Indeed 
$$1 - f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (|x_j| - (1-1/j) x_j)$$
where each term is nonnegative, and nonzero if $x_j \ne 0$.